# Deleting a character from a string Codename one

Tags: java, string, int

I'm trying to delete a % sign from a string that has numbers, something like 80%. I'm trying to just get the number and discard the % and convert it to an int. I tried:

```
String sPorcentage = findECor1().getSelectedItem().toString();
int porcentage = Integer.parseInt(sPorcentage.replaceAll("%", ""));
zona1.moveAllCurtains(porcentage);
```

It works, however the console says:

```
697: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         int porcentage = Integer.parseInt(sPorcentage.replaceAll("%", ""));
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method replaceAll(String,String)
    [javac]   location: variable sPorcentage of type String

BUILD FAILED
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Confused. Why is the quoted line in the error message different from what (you claim) you entered?

Comment: You are doing `tostring()` on `findECor2().getSelectedItem()` .. which makes me believe that the result returned is not string. Then how can it have a char `%` sign in it.

Comment: @Rahul It's likely to be a string after calling `toString`.

Comment: What version of the JDK do you have?

Comment: @AlanStokes, I mean result of this part `findECor2().getSelectedItem()` is not string type (OR) may be OP unnecessary calling tostring(). just a hunch.

Comment: When you say "it works", what do you mean? Your code has a build error but still works?

Comment: The code builds and it does what it is supposed to do, the % is gone and the value is converted to int. I have JDK 7. It is a string, however to be able to use the .replaceAll I have to use the toString. Does anyone know an alternative more codename one friendly?

Comment: The error log refers to `variable sPorcentage`, yet your code does not mention it. Can you explain us this?

Comment: Ups, copied a different portion of the code, however the correct portion does the same only using more variables, as follows
String sPorcentage = findECor1().getSelectedItem().toString();
     int porcentage = Integer.parseInt(sPorcentage.replaceAll("%", ""));
     zona1.moveAllCurtains(porcentage);

Comment: I also edited the original question

Comment: Are all your strings numbers with % at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below code instead of yours. I guess it will server your purpose:

```
String str = "80%";
int perc=Integer.parseInt(str.split("%")[0]);
System.out.println(perc);
```

The above snippet will give you the '80' as output and that too in integer variable.

Comment: I tried it, but now the compilation error is
698: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]      int porcentage = Integer.parseInt(sPorcentage.split("%")[0]);
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method split(String)
    [javac]   location: variable sPorcentage of type String

Comment: But this code is working fine with me. Can you see share actual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringUtils.replaceAll(sPorcentage, "%", "");`

Answer (score 0):

Shai already answered the question, codename one does not support some string functions like replaceAll, split. but you can use the StringUtil class they offered. StringUtil.replaceAll() will do what you want.

```
StringUtil.replaceAll(String source, String pattern, String replace);
```

source - the String source

pattern - String to replace in the source

replace - replacement String

This should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Doing a

```
int porcentage = Integer.parseInt(findECor2().getSelectedItem().toString().replaceAll("%", ""));
```

should work. However, the error you pasted indicates the variable sPorcentage was not defined.

Try defining it like in

```
        String sPorcentage = "80%";
        int porcentage = Integer.parseInt(sPorcentage.replaceAll("%", ""));
        System.out.println(porcentage);
```

Comment: There is no problem with the replacement and escaping % means nothing, you just broke the OP's code.

Comment: The OP reads the variable from somewhere - he can't just redefine it.

Comment: That's what I meant with "sPorcentage was not defined".